# Does python's print function handle unicode differently now than when Dive Into Python was written?

Tags: python, unicode, character-encoding

I'm trying to work my way through some frustrating encoding issues by going back to basics.  In Dive Into Python example 9.14 ([here](http://diveintopython.net/xml_processing/unicode.html)) we have this:

```
>>> s = u'La Pe\xf1a'
>>> print s
Traceback (innermost last): File "<interactive input>", line 1, in ?
UnicodeError: ASCII encoding error: ordinal not in range(128)
>>> print s.encode('latin-1')
La Peña
```

But on my machine, this happens:

```
>>> sys.getdefaultencoding()
'ascii'
>>> s = u'La Pe\xf1a'
>>> print s
La Peña
```

I don't understand why these are different.  Anybody?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default encoding for `print` doesn't depend on `sys.getdefaultencoding()`, but on `sys.stdout.encoding`. If you launch python with e.g. `LANG=C` or redirect a python script to a file, the encoding for stdout will be `ANSI_X3.4-1968`. On the other hand, if `sys.stdout` is a terminal, it will use the terminal's encoding.

To explain what `sys.getdefaultencoding()` does -- it's used when implicitly converting strings from/to unicode. In this example, `str(u'La Pe\xf1a')` with the default ASCII encoding would fail, but with modified default encoding it would encode the string to Latin-1. However setting the default encoding is a horrible idea, you should always use explicit encoding when you want to go from `unicode` to `str`.